# Ignore query params when pressing back button on browser

Tags: javascript, tabs, back-button, html5-history

I have a website which have tabs inside it. Recently I added the current tab name as query parameter.
Like `www.example.com/page?tab=tab1`. Here is my code which I used to implement the same.

```
var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?tab=tab1';
window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl);
```

Similary `www.example.com/page?tab=tab2` for another tab in the same page. This pattern enabled me to share the page with tab name in it and on page loading, based on the query parameter, I will show the respective tab info.

My problem is, if user presses back button, user is not going back to the previous page, instead, it shows the same page with previous tab name.

My whole purpose of adding tab name in query param was to enable link share with the tab name so that I can directly open the specific tab.

Now if user pressed back button, I want the user to navigate to the previous page, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

use [`window.history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) instead of `window.location.pushState`

replaceState modify current history entry